# Why isn't my server Reacting to input until after I disconnect?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple Server-Multi Client program that sends input from a user out to everyone.
The Server gets messages, and then sends them systematically out to everyone.

The problem I'm having is that the server gets the messages, but doesn't send them back until I disconnect from the server. I have one thread for each user, and one thread that sends out the messages.

Here is the Main server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(25566);
    SendThread SendThread = new SendThread();
    new Thread(SendThread).start();
    while(true){
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        CollectThreads socketThread = new CollectThreads(clientSocket);
        SendThread.Clients.add(socketThread);
        new Thread(socketThread).start();
    }


}
```

Here is the Input Thread(CollectThreads):

```
public Socket Client;
public CollectThreads(Socket socket)
{
    //Here we set the socket to a local variable so we can use it later
    Client = socket;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("i");
    try{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Client.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Client.getInputStream()));
        out.println("Connected");
        boolean x = true;
        while(x){
            String s;
            if((s = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(s);
                SendThread.log.add(s);
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
    }

}
```

And the Sender(SendThread):

```
public ArrayList<CollectThreads> Clients = new ArrayList<CollectThreads>();
public static ArrayList<String> log = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
    while(true){
        String x;
        while(!Clients.isEmpty()){
            x = log.get(0);
            for(int c = 0; c < Clients.size(); c += 1){
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Clients.get(c).Client.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(x);
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            log.remove(0);
        }
    }
    } catch(IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
    }
}
```

If I input x, The server console prints x, I disconnect, and then it prints x the second time.
Can anyone find my mistake? or tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: Your server doesn't react to readLine() returning null properly. It should close the socket and exit the loop. At present it is hard-looping at EOS.

Comment: @EJP This was a mock up to see if this works, I'll fix that soon

Comment: Mock ups still have to work. Doing it wrong the first time has no benefit. It just gives you something else to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never removing anything from SendThread.Clients, so I can't see why it won't just keep resending the same thing indefinitely.

It's a very strange design. Why not have each client thread send its own output, like everybody else?

Comment: Then how would I make sure that every Client thread outputs the message before deleting it from the buffer? And then how would I prevent it from sending a message twice?

Comment: By taking the hint in my last sentence?